# Android Cursor Adapter with Multiple Layouts- Null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, listadapter, android-cursoradapter

I apologize in advance for the formatting below. I haven't posted much to this site. I am getting a null pointer exception at line 148 of bind view, specifically at the lines:

```
AdditionalInfoView additionalInfoView = (AdditionalInfoView) view.getTag();
additionalInfoView.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
```

I'm confident that the layout has a textfield with the id title and that the database has data in the title column. I'm not sure if this method is working AT ALL though, and it is just randomly giving me an error there when the problem is really happening way earlier.

I'm trying to implement a listview that can handle multiple types of data so I can dynamically create pages with the pieces of data I want. Am I doing this correctly? Is there a better implementation? Or is this just not recommended at all? Full code for the adapter below:

One note- I saw some implementations that had a count of different types of layouts the listadapter is displaying. Do I need to set that somewhere?

**EDIT**
I've wrapped all the calls to the cursor in isNull() to make sure that it isn't the cursor that isn't working. I'm still getting an error, so I think that something must be wrong with the view somehow.

```
/** ResourcesAdapter
*
* This takes in a cursor for the resources table and attaches the
* appropriate view to the appropriate data field. Fields are:
* AdditionalInfo
* Address
* AppLink
* Paragraph
* Phone
* Space
* TextWithBullets
* TitleBreak
* WebLink
*
* TODO- I'm totally skipping AppLink for later.
*/
public class ResourcesAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ResourcesAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

static class PhoneView {
    TextView title;
    TextView phone;
}

static class TitleBreakView {
    TextView title;
}

static class AdditionalInfoView {
    TextView title;
}

static class AddressView {
    TextView title;
    TextView address;
}

static class AppLinkView {
    TextView title;
}

static class ParagraphView {
    TextView paragraph;
}

static class TextWithBulletsView {
    TextView text;
    TextView bullet1;
    TextView bullet2;
    TextView bullet3;
    TextView bullet4;
    TextView bullet5;
}

static class WebLinkView {
    TextView title;
}

/** newView
*
* This method gets the views that we later bind the data to. Supposedly this will recycle views
* too, but it's not the convertView method I'm used to from array adapters. If it's happening,
* its happening in the background.
**/
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("Phone")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.phone, parent, false);
        PhoneView phoneView = new PhoneView();
        phoneView.title = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        phoneView.phone = (TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.phone));
        view.setTag(phoneView);
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("TitleBreak")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.title_break, parent, false);
        TitleBreakView titleBreakView = new TitleBreakView();
        titleBreakView.title = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        view.setTag(titleBreakView);
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("AdditionalInfo")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.additional_info, parent, false);
        AdditionalInfoView additionalInfoView = new AdditionalInfoView();
        additionalInfoView.title = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        view.setTag(additionalInfoView);
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("Address")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.address, parent, false);
        AddressView addressView = new AddressView();
        addressView.title = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        addressView.address = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.address));
        view.setTag(addressView);
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("AppLink")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.app_link, parent, false);
        AppLinkView appLinkView = new AppLinkView();
        appLinkView.title = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        view.setTag(appLinkView);
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("Paragraph")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.paragraph, parent, false);
        ParagraphView paragraphView = new ParagraphView();
        paragraphView.paragraph = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.paragraph));
        view.setTag(paragraphView);
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("Space")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.space, parent, false);
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("TextWithBullets")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.text_with_bullets, parent, false);
        TextWithBulletsView textWithBulletsView = new TextWithBulletsView();
        textWithBulletsView.text = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.text));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet1 = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.bullet1));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet2 = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.bullet2));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet3 = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.bullet3));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet4 = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.bullet4));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet5 = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.bullet5));
        view.setTag(textWithBulletsView);
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("WebLink")) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.web_link, parent, false);
        WebLinkView webLinkView = new WebLinkView();
        webLinkView.title = (TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        view.setTag(webLinkView);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("Phone")) {
        PhoneView phoneView = (PhoneView) view.getTag();
        phoneView.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
        phoneView.phone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data1")));
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("TitleBreak")) {
        TitleBreakView titleBreakView = (TitleBreakView) view.getTag();
        titleBreakView.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("AdditionalInfo")) {
        AdditionalInfoView additionalInfoView = (AdditionalInfoView) view.getTag();
        additionalInfoView.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("Address")) {
        AddressView addressView = (AddressView) view.getTag();
        addressView.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
        addressView.address.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data1")));
        //TODO-Properly format the address
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("AppLink")) {
        AppLinkView appLinkView = (AppLinkView) view.getTag();
        appLinkView.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("Paragraph")) {
        ParagraphView paragraphView = (ParagraphView) view.getTag();
        paragraphView.paragraph.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data1")));
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("Space")) {
        //Does something need to go here? It's just a spacer!
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("TextWithBullets")) {
        TextWithBulletsView textWithBulletsView = (TextWithBulletsView) view.getTag();
        textWithBulletsView.text.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data1")));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data2")));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data3")));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet4.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data4")));
        textWithBulletsView.bullet5.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data5")));
    } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("WebLink")) {
        WebLinkView webLinkView = (WebLinkView) view.getTag();
        webLinkView.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are multiple places in those two lines of code where an NPE could occur. I recommend using Android Studio, setting a breakpoint on those lines, and [debugging](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html) so you can get a better idea what's happening.

Comment: Yes, this was kind of an obvious error. Now that this code works though, I'll leave this up as an example for how to implement multiple layouts within a single list view.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The above implementation is fully correct. The problem was that because I was using the name R.id.title for all these different layouts to be consistent, which obscured that I forgot to add a R.id.title TextView to that particular layout. I thought I checked that first, but there were so many different layouts I think I looked at the wrong one. Below is how I checked to make sure the problem wasn't with the cursor:

```
if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"))) {
    additionalInfoView.title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
}
```